# Play video in loop from the selected duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a video file in my design which has length of 2min. For the first time the video will play from the beginning and then the video have to play from 1.00 sec to 2.00 sec in loop. Is this possible to do using jquery? I have tried alternative methods. It works but there is a jump in video. [Change video source after the first video ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745504/change-video-source-after-the-first-video-ends).

Here are the code I have:

JQuery:

```
document.getElementById('bgvid').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);

function myHandler(e) {
   //*what to do?*//
}
```

HTML:

```
div class="anim-logo ">
    <video playsinline autoplay muted  poster="assets/img/video3.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="assets/img/video3.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="assets/img/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
      </div><!--end of anim logo-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('videoElm')
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    // set the video's start position to the video's duration minus 10 seconds. "video.currentTime" is in milliseconds, "video.duration" is in seconds
    video.currentTime = (parseInt(video.duration) - 10) * 1000;
    video.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <video id="videoElm" autoplay muted>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/webm">
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: no.. first time ( every page load ) it plays from the beginning. after that it have play the last 60 sec in loop.

Comment: @SharavnanKv I've edited my answer to address that. Change the video's `currentTime` to seek to a specific time in the video, and change the second argument of the `setInterval(...)` function to see how long the loop should be.

Comment: video load issue :)

Comment: @SharavnanKv It works on my system, maybe it is a browser compatibility issue, I'm using Chrome. Try it with another video.

Comment: @SharavnanKv I've changed my answer again. You can also try this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9ntzb0k4/)

Comment: @SharavnanKv I've edited my answer, it should do what you want now. Try to understand what that code does so you will be able to adjust it yourself if you want to change what it does.